# SOAP API on ISPconfig 3

Tags: php, soap, ispconfig

I have seen a couple post on how to use the SOAP API and just can't seem to get it to authentic, I just receive the following message:
SOAP Error: The login failed. Username or password wrong

I know the user/password details are correct but I can't managed to a more descriptive error message.

```
<?php
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'password';
$soap_location = 'https://test.uk:8080/remote/index.php';
$soap_uri = 'https://test.uk:8080/remote/';
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => $soap_location, 'uri'      => $soap_uri));
try {
    //* Login to the remote server
    if($session_id = $client->login($username,$password)) {
        echo 'Logged into remote server successfully. The SessionID is '.$session_id.'';
    }
                //* Logout
        if($client->logout($session_id)) {
                echo "FTP Created";
        }
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
        die('SOAP Error: '.$e->getMessage());
        echo "Please contact the server administator";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for this was a little patchy, the reason I wasn't able to connect was because I hadn't created a specific remote user in ISPconfig.

Loaded the web interface, clicked system, then selected remote users on the left hand side. You can create your user here and then use those details to connect and use the API.